# How can I view my FPS?

Tags: pc, crysis-3

On Windows, how would I go about displaying the FPS in Crysis 3?

I found some console commands on this link
[Crysis 3: PC Developer Console Commands](http://www.gamefront.com/crysis-3-pc-developer-console-commands)
*pressing **~** doesn't bring up the console on my computer but **`** (above the tab key) does*

The instructions don't mention how to display FPS.

I found this
[Show fps Crysis?](http://www.overclock.net/t/252374/show-fps-crysis#post_2907515)

Which says to enter the following

```
r_DisplayInfo = 1
```

But the command doesn't seem to do anything in Crysis 3, when I enter it into the console I get this message

```
r_DisplayInfo = 1 [DUMPTODISK, RESTRICTEDMODE]
```

Comment: It's a `RESTRICTEDMODE` command, you use `con_restricted 0` to unlock it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed by a [Crytek Community Manager](http://games.on.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=198306&p=2660133#p2660249) there is no native way to show a frames per second counter or graph in Crysis 3. Various other sources all recommend using an external utility like MSI Afterburner, EVGA Precision X or FRAPS to display the current frames per second counter, but the possible side effect of running such utility is that it may lower your actual FPS.

Comment: FRAPS is rather light, I doubt it really makes an impact on the FPS. As long as you use it only to display the FPS, of course.

Comment: yeah, fraps by far most easiest way to do this and actually pretty light on using resources.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to get the FPS but it's not what I was hoping for. I would prefer to see the FPS in real-time.

##### To see what the FPS is at a given moment

Bring up the console by pressing the **`** key. On my keyboard, it's the key beneath the escape key and above the tab key.

Enter the following command into the console

```
r_GetScreenShot 2
```

A screenshot is taken and the FPS is displayed in the console.

Here is a picture of what it looks like:
[image: crysis 3 screenshot]

*The FPS is near the bottom of the console in light blue text*

I noticed how to do this while watching the "Crysis 3 - Quick Guide To PC Console Commands" GameFront VODs video: